# How to constrain the merging of bounding boxes of characters to form words with PyTesseract

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using [PyTesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) for an OCR task on numbers. I am encountering a case where (as demonstrated below) two numbers are merged together in the OCR output.

[image: Outputs (2736, 2260791954)]

This outputs `[2736, 2260791954]` after stripping and splitting the string result from `image_to_string` whereas I would expect `[2736, 22607, 21254]`.

EDIT: results are obtained from running the following lines on the presented image:

```py
num_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(processed_frame, config="outputbase digits -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789")
numbers = [int(x) for x in num_text.split()]
return numbers
```

I didn't find anything in the CLI arguments that would help me constrain the rules with which bounding boxes for characters are merged and I'm trying to not have to extract individual bounding boxes and merge them manually if possible.

I was wondering if there was a way to make it so that it's able to separate the two numbers without much manual interference.

Comment: Please add the code that causes the error.

Comment: There are no errors per se, only what I described in the question but I've added the exact snippet I'm using for OCR nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

The [page segmentation method](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#tools--libraries:%7E:text=images%20using%20OpenCV-,Page%20segmentation%20method,-By%20default%20Tesseract) will help you. Using -

> 11 Sparse text. Find as much text as possible in no particular order

, you can easily find all the numbers in the image. Then filter out the ones you need and convert the strings into numbers.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

processed_frame = cv2.imread('AVLaD.png')

num_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(processed_frame, config='--psm 11').split()
print(num_text)
numbers = [int(x.replace(',', '')) for x in num_text if len(x) > 3]
print(numbers)

-----------------------------

['50', '2,736', '100', '150', '200', '22,607', '21,254', '250', '300', '350', '50', '100', '150', '200', '250', '300', '350', '400']
[2736, 22607, 21254]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know beforehand what numbers I'm going to need unless I manually check the image myself. For instance you're hardcoding the `len(x) > 3` condition here which I don't necessarily have.

Comment: @Minuano
  You probably need to ask a new question, or try to solve this problem yourself. Since the answer to the division of sticking numbers is given. I don't see the rest of your samples, but the first thing that comes to mind is to paint black the white frame along the perimeter along with the axis numbers.